# where is libMobileGestalt.dylib

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to know how to implement MGCopyAnswer.SO I want to use IDA to reveal 
libMobileGestalt.dylib,but the libMobileGestalt.dylib of xcode can't be reveal.Please tell me how can I do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need to jailbreak you iOS, and find it at "/usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib"

Comment: follow this http://newosxbook.com/articles/guesstalt.html, and you can find jtool here http://www.newosxbook.com/tools/jtool.html